# Android sniffer

Tags: java, android, сеть, wifi

Привет всем.

Хочу сделать сниффер на андроид, который ловил бы все пакеты по wi-fi.
Зачем это нужно: нужно соединить несколько устройств не по протоколам стандарта 802.11. Гуглил, в сети много чего упирается в Wi-Fi Direct, но это все не то. Пытаюсь создать свой протокол, не привязываться к уже имеющимся.
Пробовал работать с Wi-Fi Direct-ом, там возникала одна проблема: при соединении устройств, выкидывалась табличка с просьбой на разрешения соединения, этот вопрос тоже имеется, не знаю, только ли в Wi-Fi Direct такое разрешение требуется.

Посоветуйте статьи, примеры кода сниффера под Android, все что может помочь)

Comment: Android Studio один из инструментов разработки под Android и к вопросу отношения не имеет. В любой среде разработки решение будет одинаковым.